# RavenDB: How to query many different documents in a single query?

Tags: search, ravendb

I am new to RavenDB and I'm not sure how to address this issue.

I have a document store with around 200 different document types. Each type can contain thousands of documents.

In my business logic all the different document types are treated the same - they can be all mapped to a generic object such as a DataTable.

I would like to query all the properties of all the documents from all types in a single free text search. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using multi maps. Take a look at this post:

http://ayende.com/blog/156225/relational-searching-sucks-donrsquo-t-try-to-replicate-it